# Зачем нужны круглые скобки в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть вопрос по MySQL. 
Про круглые скобки в справочниках написано это:
круглые скобки используются для задания порядка вычислений в выражении. Например:

```
mysql> SELECT 1+2*3;
        -> 7
mysql> SELECT (1+2)*3;
        -> 9
```

Плюс, круглые скобки используются в подзапросах. Больше про использование круглых скобок я не нашел ничего.

```
(SELECT * FROM sales2005) UNION (SELECT * FROM sales2006);
```

**Зачем запросы берутся в круглые скобки? Когда вообще в MySQL надо ставить круглые скобки и для чего они служат?**

Если, например, написать запрос для тестовой БД world, чтобы из таблицы с городами выбрало русские и украинские города

```
(SELECT name FROM city WHERE countrycode='RUS' ORDER BY name) 
UNION 
(SELECT name FROM city WHERE countrycode='UKR');
```

то **русские города почему-то не упорядочиваются по алфавиту. Почему?**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке выше видно, что первым городом идет Moscow, хотя первым должен быть город на "A".

Если можно, то напишите с примерами, чтобы лучше было понятно.

Спасибо

Comment: [Документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Comment: у меня не сработал GROUP BY внутри: (SELECT name FROM city WHERE countrycode='RUS' ORDER BY name) UNION (SELECT name FROM city WHERE countrycode='UKR');

Comment: Документация вполне чётко говорит - скобки нужны для сортировки отдельного подзапроса. Так что сортировка сработала (суслика видишь?). Другой вопрос, что потом UNION ещё одну пересортировку делает - после чего от перовой ничего не остаётся. И опять же документация говорит, что делать в этом случае.

Comment: какой суслик? у меня не отсортировались русские города по алфавиту. какую UNION делает пересортировку?

Comment: *у меня не отсортировались русские города по алфавиту* Это ошибочное утверждение (суслика видишь? а он есть...).

Comment: я добавил картинку-скриншот, на которой видно, что первым городом идет Moscow

Comment: *какую UNION делает пересортировку?* UNION (а в полной версии это UNION DISTINCT) удаляет дубликаты. Делается это путём сортировки общего (объединённого) набора и затем удаления дубликатов из полученного сортированного набора. При этом само собой имевшаяся у исходных данных сортировка идёт лесом. Тот самый суслик, который есть, но которого ты не видишь...

Comment: так зачем тогда есть возможность сортировки, например, такой - (SELECT name FROM city WHERE countrycode='RUS' ORDER BY name) UNION (SELECT name FROM city WHERE countrycode='UKR');  -  если все равно ее в итоге не будет, а все будет перемешано как попало?

Comment: *зачем тогда есть возможность сортировки* Для того, чтобы можно было ограничить (LIMIT) выборку подзапроса. А без ограничения сортировка отдельного подзапроса - бессмысленна.

Comment: теперь понятно. спасибо

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * from (SELECT `message` FROM `messages` ORDER BY `message`)as b
UNION ALL
SELECT * from (SELECT `sender` FROM `messages`) as a
```

таким способом будет работать order by для первой выборки, а скобки нужны для логического разделения, т е так написать можно:

```
SELECT `message` FROM `messages`
UNION ALL
SELECT `sender` FROM `messages`
```

но так будет ошибка:

```
SELECT `message` FROM `messages` ORDER BY `message`
UNION ALL
SELECT `sender` FROM `messages`
```

а если поставить скобочки, то все хорошо :

```
(SELECT `message` FROM `messages` ORDER BY `message`)
UNION ALL
(SELECT `sender` FROM `messages`)
```

т.е. несколько логических операций должны отделяться скобочками (на подобии иерархии строится для запроса).

Comment: UNION ALL и UNION DISTINCT - это настолько сильно отличающиеся (несмотря на синтаксическую схожесть) операции, что проводить параллели между заданным исходно вопросом и этим ответом как минимум странно.

Comment: человек спросил как сделать - я ответил, вот и все.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. плюсанул